# On production protocol change from https to http on server

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2, codeigniter-4

I am using the latest version of `select2` with `Codeigniter 4`

I have 3-4 dropdown with ajax search on same page. And when page load select2 initialized on those dropdown.
On the same page I am using `base_url` to create dynamic Url.

### Sections are

#### This is form action

```
action="<?= base_url('requests/booking/' . (isset($file['myId']) ? $file['myId'] : '')) ?>"

And it converted to 

https://mysiteurl.com/requests/booking/myId
```

Above code generates `https` url with same as domain.

#### This is dropdown section

I set these attributes in my dropdown with select 2

```
<select class="ms select2 select2-ajax companyAddress"
     data-call-url="<?= base_url('ajax/bookingShipperAddress') ?>"
     data-placeholder="Company">
</select>
```

In above section when it initialized the `data-call-url`, It's protocol change to `http` instead of `https`
There are also more dropdown except only url endpoint changed.

#### My JQuery Code.

```
applySelect2: function (className = 'select2-ajax') {
    $('.' + className).each(function () {
        var url = $(this).data('call-url');
        let placeholder = $(this).data('placeholder');
        if (url && ((url != "undefined") || (url != "undefined"))) {
            $(this).select2({
                placeholder: placeholder ?? 'Select an option',
                ajax: {
                    url : url,
                    dataType: 'json'
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(this).select2({
                placeholder: 'Select an option'
            });
        }
        $(this).removeClass(className)
    });
    /**
     * Use below code to get other variable for selected value
     *
     *  var select2Obj = $(this).select2('data').find(item => item.element.selected);
     */
}
```

Although It works on my local because of `http` but not on `production`

See these Screenshots of element code of server

. Check form url with page url. [Link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deviserops/deviserops/master/asset/formUrl2.gif)
. Check dropdown url with page url. [Link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deviserops/deviserops/master/asset/ddUrl2.gif)

Comment: What happens when you explicitly pass the protocol as second parameter? `data-call-url="<?= base_url('ajax/bookingShipperAddress', 'https') ?>"`

Comment: Same, even if I pass `https` as second param it will still go to http.

Comment: Although It's showing https everywhere on same page. Like form action url, image url etc

Comment: How did you define the `app.baseURL` configuration in your `.env` file?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for trying out the answer for this.
But I got the answer here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests

##### This is what I got.

`The HTTP Content-Security-Policy (CSP) upgrade-insecure-requests directive instructs user agents to treat all of a site's insecure URLs (those served over HTTP) as though they have been replaced with secure URLs (those served over HTTPS). This directive is intended for web sites with large numbers of insecure legacy URLs that need to be rewritten.`

##### Answer:

I have to add this meta tag in my main layout file. This will send request according to `http` or `https` protocols for my server

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```